# Reactjs não importa o css

Tags: react

Gostaria de saber qual é o problema com o:

```
import './styles.css'.
```

O erro é o seguinte:

> `./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css) Error: No valid exports main found for 'C:\Users\Serginho\Desktop\React-Native\DreamJob\__test__\teste\node_modules\colorette'`

eu já desenvolvo em React Native, mas eu não tenho muito conhecimento nos erros do ReactJs.

Comment: tem como colocar todo o código do componente?

Answer (score -3):

Aquele ponto depois do .css pode ser seu erro, retire e deixe somente assim:

import './styles.css'